# Как подгружать скрипт в зависимости от разрешения экрана

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Господа выручайте. Имеется скрипт, вот такого вида - знаю, скрипт костыльный, совсем не разбираюсь в javascript , но суть не в этом (работает и то хорошо) , необходимо загружать его только в том случае если разрешение экрана браузера больше 1010px, иначе нужно просто игнорировать его. Заранее премного благодарен.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var liNum = 1;
  $(".fullstory-menu ul li").each(function() {
    $(this).children("meta").attr("content", liNum);
    liNum++;
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".header-menu").click(function(){
  $(".right-coloumn").toggleClass("active"); return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если речь про разрешение экрана, а не размер окна, то так:

```
if (screen.width > 1010) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто оберни код в условие. Если нужно чтоб при динамическом изменении окна этот код отрабатывал, то ниже еще пример кода

```js
if ($(window).width() > 1010) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var liNum = 1;
    $(".fullstory-menu ul li").each(function() {
      $(this).children("meta").attr("content", liNum);
      liNum++;
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".header-menu").click(function(){
      $(".right-coloumn").toggleClass("active"); return false;
    });
  });
}
//Если нужно чтоб при изменении размера окна код отрабатывал
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(this).width() > 1010) {

      var liNum = 1;
      $(".fullstory-menu ul li").each(function() {
        $(this).children("meta").attr("content", liNum);
        liNum++;
      });
  }
});
$(".header-menu").click(function(){
  if ($(window).width() < 1010) return;
  $(".right-coloumn").toggleClass("active"); 
  return false;
});
```